# Number field analogue of the Goldbach Conjecture

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, number-fields, goldbach-type-problems

Is there a generalization of Goldbachs conjecture for prime ideals in number fields?

Answer (score 17):

Googling the obvious, «Goldbach number fields», comes up with a bunch of relevant results, In particular, a link to [Takayoshi MITSUI,
On the Goldbach problem in an algebraic number field I. J. Math. Soc. Japan, Vol 12, No. 3, 1960] [here](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/journal-of-the-mathematical-society-of-japan/volume-12/issue-3/On-the-Goldbach-problem-in-an-algebraic-number-field-I/10.2969/jmsj/01230290.full)

Comment: Sigh, this should have been a comment.

Comment: Why? Looks like an answer to me. 

Comment: Well... If the result of typing "golbach numbr fields" into google and copying the 2nd result is the answer, the question cannot be that good :)

Comment: So, good questions deserve answers, bad questions deserve comments? Yeah, I can sorta see that. 